# Oracle ADF 12c deployment to Tomcat or Glassfish

Tags: oracle-adf

Does anyone have experience successfully deploying an ADF 12c application to either Tomcat (7 or 8) or Glassfish 3.1?

I am having difficulty getting this accomplished and could use some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ADF Essentials for deployment that are not on WebLogic.
Info here: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/adfessentials-1719844.html

Comment: Thanks Shay. I know and am working with ADF Essentials.
I've followed the instructions on a couple of websites for deploying to Glassfish and Tomcat but to no avail. The error I get when I deploy to Glassfish is too generic and I'm getting a number of errors when I deploy to Tomcat. I'm trying to find someone who has accomplished this successfully and can provide some help on more than answering a question here and there basis. I'm willing to pay for that help too. I'm just so fed up and frustrated with trying to get my app deployed already.

Comment: I even tried calling Oracle Consulting Services to hire a consultant to help but was passed around to 8 different people over about a 30 minute period none of whom could answer the questions:
1. Do they have someone who can help with this issue and 
2. How much would it cost on an hourly basis

Answer (score 0):

This maybe late, but I would like to add the following:
ADF Essentials are not supported on Glassfish 3.1, please see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/122-cert-2708091.html. You have to install it on Glassfish 4.1.